# How can we create new options in SharePoint doc library ribbon?

Tags: 2013, ribbon

We are using SharePoint 2013 for intranet portal. Not apps.

We have a document library with documents. On clicking the document library we can see the list of documents. I want to place a clickable item on the ribbon of the doc library such that, when we click on a document, then I want to enable this button in ribbon and onclick redirect to an application page with the selected doc id.

I would also like to know the number of possible ways to do this and the best practice.

Comment: look at this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfrost/archive/2009/11/06/adding-custom-button-to-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this:

Invoke server side code on SharePoint ribbon click using javascript submit

```
function RibbonDemo() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var itemIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        itemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }
    var pageUrl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(
        '/SharePointRibbonDemo/RibbonDemo.aspx?ids=' + itemIds + '&listId=' + listId);
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", pageUrl);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();   
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Failed));
}
```

Invoke server side code on SharePoint ribbon click using javascript `_dopostback`

```
function RibbonDemo() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var itemIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        itemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }
    __doPostBack('RibbonDemo', itemIds + ";" + listId);    
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Failed));
}
```

Invoke server side code on SharePoint ribbon click using SharePoint Page dialog

```
function RibbonDemo() {
 var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var itemIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        itemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }
    var pageUrl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(
        '/SharePointRibbonDemo/RibbonDemo.aspx?ids=' + itemIds + '&listId=' + listId);
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.width = 500;
    options.height = 300;
    options.url = pageUrl;
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, OnDialogClose);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 }

 function OnDialogClose(result, target) {
    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        alert('OK was clicked");
  }
 }
```

See this for more info: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2012/07/invoke-server-side-code-on-sharepoint.html